# The standard deviation

Tags: statistics, random-variables, standard-deviation

If I have a sample data and compute the standard deviation
and then change them by adding several zeroes to their end
then the standard deviation won't change. How can I **prove** this fact ? It works by trial and error in Excell.

Comment: You won't.  If you had only one sample, say $1$, the standard deviation equals zero. If you add a zero the standard deviation becomes positive.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I now understand the problem: the way I tried it, it ignores empty cells rather then adding 0 to the sample.